# Regular expressions: a character cannot show more than 4 times in a sequence

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a regular expression where the string MUST start with E, can have unlimited E's (E+), and MUST end with C ([C]).

Then B can OPTIONALLY be between E and C, but only in pairs (B{2}?).

Now this is the part I'm stuck on. There cannot be more than 4 P's in the string. I am trying to use S{0,4}.

Lastly, each P or sequence of P's in the series MUST be followed by a D.

I've been experimenting a lot but can't figure out the P and D.

Comment: Can there is other letters also between `E` and `C` such as `A`, `F`, `T` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^E+(?!(?:[^P\n]*P){5})(?:B{2}|P+D)*C$
```

- `(?!(?:[^P\n]*P){5})` - Make sure there are no more than 5 Ps on this line. Do this in a *negative lookahead*, rather than consuming the characters, to allow for more logic
- `(?:B{2}|P+D)*` - Every substring in the middle either needs to be a B pair, or some Ps followed by a D

https://regex101.com/r/2tg7Mr/1

Comment: Hi thanks for giving an explanation helping me understand. What does the '!' do, I haven't learned this symbol yet.

Comment: The full construct is `(?!SOMETHING)`, called negative lookahead. Eg `a(?!b)` will only match an `a` which is not followed by a `b`. It makes sure that the current position is not followed by what matches in the negative lookahead.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks so much!